# Auto High light the selected word in textpad(version 6.X)

Tags: textpad

[image]

HI All

I am looking for a feature in Textpad, which will highlight all the occurrences of selected word. This might not be very useful for all cases. But i found this very interesting in Notepad++.

Is there any option to make this happen in Textpad as well.

Answer (score 1):

May not be possible in Textpad6. There have been Enhancement Suggestion requests in the Textpad community.